# PHP call a method on a ReflectionClass

Tags: php, laravel, reflection, phpunit

I'm a novice developer trying to write a test suite for an existing Laravel app.  Currently I'm trying to write tests for a controller but the authentication system used is strangely implemented and difficult to get around.  I can't simply:

```
$user = \User::find(1);
$this->be($user);
```

I need to instantiate the controller and set a private property in its base class.  To get around this, I'm trying to use reflection and setting the constructor properties and the user property manually.  My issue arises when I try to invoke the method on the reflection object and I don't know how to get around it.  My test method:

```
public function testCount()
{
    $user = \User::find(1);
    $this->be($user);

    $leadRepositoryInterface = m::mock('CRM\Storage\Lead\LeadRepositoryInterface');
    $response = m::mock('ColorJar\ApiResponse\Response');

    $leadsController = new ReflectionClass('LeadsController');

    $leadsControllerLead = $leadsController->getProperty('lead');
    $leadsControllerLead->setAccessible(true);
    $leadsControllerResponse = $leadsController->getProperty('response');
    $leadsControllerResponse->setAccessible(true);
    $leadsControllerCrmuser = $leadsController->getProperty('crmUser');
    $leadsControllerCrmuser->setAccessible(true);

    $leadsControllerLead->setValue($leadsController, $leadRepositoryInterface);
    $leadsControllerResponse->setValue($leadsController, $response);
    $leadsControllerCrmuser->setValue($leadsController, $user);

    $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('ReflectionClass', 'count');

    $this->assertEquals('jdsf', $reflectionMethod->invoke($leadsController));
}
```

generates the following error:

```
LeadsControllerTest::testCount
ReflectionException: Method ReflectionClass::count() does not exist
```

I realize that I'm calling count() on an instance of ReflectionClass instead of LeadsController but I don't know how else to set these properties, in particular the crmUser since it's a private property of the class that LeadsController inherits from.  How do I make this work?

Comment: You should provide correct class or object: new ReflectionMethod('ReflectionClass', 'count'); in parameter 'ReflectionClass'

Comment: That's what I tried first.  If I provide 'LeadsController' there, I get the following error:
ReflectionException: Given object is not an instance of the class this method was declared in

Comment: Try to replace 'ReflectionClass' (string) to $leadsController

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHPUnit's Mock feature.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Example 9.7: Stubbing a method call to return a value from a callback

will propably be helpful, you can configure, what result your call to "count" does.

Comment: Really?  Are you sure I should be mocking the class I'm testing?

Comment: Yes.  setMethods(array $methods) gives you the power to decide which methods are actually replaced. You just override the getters to your private properties, and configure what they would return. Like `$stub->method('count')->willReturn(2);`. If you want, i will expand my answer with an example.

Comment: @brianfr82 no, you should avoid mocking the class you're testing. Read more about testing in Laravel first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing

Comment: @JakubZalas Thanks.  That's what I thought.  If I were to mock the object I'm testing, I'd be mocking everything and thus testing nothing.

Comment: @brianfr82 you dont need to mock everything. With phpunit's mocking capabilities you can mock just the methods you want, the rest remains the same.

setMethods(array $methods) can be called on the Mock Builder object to specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you call setMethods(null), then no methods will be replaced

Comment: @Fivetide I'm still really inexperienced so I get what you're saying but don't really know how to implement it.  I'm using Mockery for mocking and phpunit for actual testing.  I need to read up on all this stuff

Comment: @brianfr82 Mockery can do partial mocks too. see http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html
You can use this to do the same you did with reflection, override methods like "getUser", while keeping the methods you want to test just like they are.

Comment: @Fivetide, my problem has changed quite a bit since I originally posted this question.  My only lingering issue(I think) is that I need to set the return of Input::all() to return my user but I'm not really sure how to do that.  Input is a laravel thing and I'm lost as to how to set it